# Magento Base theme add review page 2colunms-right layout change to 1columns laylout

Tags: magento

I want to custom a theme with base theme package.

I have change my detail product page to 1 columns layout.

When i click the 'Add Your Review' links in detail page . Then it go to the url like index.php/review/product/list/id/5/category/3/#review-form But it is 2 columns-right layout.

how to change it to 1 columns layout ?

I have try to do it in review.xml

```
   <reviews>
    <!-- Mage_Review -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</reviews>
```

change to 1column.phtml ,but it's not work.

Comment: did you refreshed layout and block/html output cache after you changed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in  `review_product_list` Handler

```
<review_product_list>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</review_product_list>
```

Hope This Help !!

Comment: Yeah! It works , I have searach it in google all day . Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Great !! If it work accept the answer. So that it help other as well.

Comment: Ok , I must accept it after 10 minutes. you answer was really fast.